# Should OPs get any special treatment when suggesting edits to answers on their question?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Every now and then I see the poster of a question suggesting some edit to one of the answers on it. Usually this is in the form of some more specifically-useful code (on SO) or the like: taking a shortcut in cases where arguably the question wasn't quite specified well enough and the answer is correspondingly lacking a bit.

To what extent, if any, should they get special treatment in changing/adding the details of the answer to better fit their own question?

[Why do question-askers edit answers when trying to explain/edit their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102530/why-do-question-askers-edit-answers-when-trying-to-explain-edit-their-question) seems to suggest that a little bit of extra leeway might be acceptable, but it's not entirely clear; also, the answer is pretty old and not very highly-voted.

If they *should* get some special treatment, can we please get some special formatting to denote "this suggester was the original asker", like the blue highlighting for OP approval and such?

(I believe this is, in principle, applicable on any network site. I could be mistaken, however. [Motivating suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8007946).)

Answer (score 7):

I see nothing wrong with the asker of a question suggesting edits to any of its answers.

However, while it may be useful to notice whether the question and suggested edits to someone else's answer come from the same person, there is no reason for any special treatment to be considered.

Every question and answer, and any edits to either, should be treated on their merits, irrespective of who has asked, answered or edited them.